# comma separated list with semicolon in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

I have a table in sql ssms with values as follows:

```
RID | Comments|                 Date               |Date Without Miliseconds


----------
780 |General Comment 2  |2016-11-20 14:12:44.097 |2016-11-20 14:12:44.000

----------


780 |General Comment 1  |2016-11-20 14:05:23.687    |2016-11-20 14:05:23.000


----------


780 |Document comment 1 |2016-11-20 14:05:23.687|2016-11-20 14:05:23.000


----------

780 |DEIRDRE Nominations1 |2016-11-20 14:05:23.390  |2016-11-20 14:05:23.000
```

So I want the output as follows:

```
----------
RID |List of Comments


----------


780 |General Comment 1,Document comment 1,DEIRDRE Nominations1; General Comment 2
```

I don't want to modify table schema. I added the Date without Miliiseconds column so that it will be easy to group by.
Comments from Same DateTime should be separated by comma and from different dateTime should be spearated by semicolon ';'

Can you help me with this?

Thanks,
Swarda

Answer (score 2):

You can use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for this.

```
SELECT RID, GROUP_CONCAT(Comments SEPARATOR ';') AS ListOfComments 
FROM table 
GROUP BY RID;
```

Comment: It will show values separated by comma, we need to use `separator` to get the desired output.

Comment: hey, Thanks for your help but I want the comments separated by comma  ',' with same time and then semicolon ';' to separate the comments from different time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `group_concat` with `concat` to format the values, e.g.:

```
select id, concat(group_concat(comment), ';') as comments
from comments
group by id;
```

Here's **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c7dc9/6/0)**.

Comment: hey, Thanks for your help but I want the comments separated by comma  ',' with same time and then semicolon ';' to separate the comments from different time.